# Returning a value from a Stored proc as an Output parameter vs a SELECT statement

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql

A very silly example, but if I need to get the max order ID out of the orders table and I have two options (I know there are more, but I'm just interested in these two).  I'm interested in knowing which ends up being less overhead.

A first one that simply selects the value out:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetLastOrderID
AS
SELECT Max(OrderID) FROM Orders
```

and then corresponding C# code to create a SQLCommand to execute the proc, call .ExecuteScalar, and cast the value to an int.

A second one that passes the value out as an output parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetLastOrderID (@MaxOrderID INT OUTPUT)
AS
SET @MaxOrderId = Max(OrderID) FROM Orders
```

and then corresponding C# code to create a SQLCommand to execute the proc, add an output parameter of type int, then call .ExecuteNonQuery, and finally get the value of the output parameter.

Is there any real benefit of one over the other?  My gut feel is that the first option will take more time/resources because there's no explicit types given, but I'd love to know if there's a definitive answer out there. (or at least one that beats my "gut feel" in terms of authority)

Comment: `OPUTPUT` parameters are meant to be significantly more lightweight than constructing and returning a recordset. I have no idea by how much though. Should be easy to test this yourself by creating 2 versions and calling them in a loop.

Comment: @Martin : they are lighter, but unless you are calling very many times, the difference is small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The overhead of which you are referring to is neglible compared to actually running the TSQL MAX() statement on anything except a trivial number of rows.

Use the form that is most understandable and most maintainable.

Worry about performance when you have identified a performance problem.

Comment: Bearing in mind, this was a "silly" example. You've not really answered the question, just said that this particular example negligable so it doesn't matter.Perhaps a better example would be inserting a value into a table and getting back the ID of the new row?

Comment: @Paul Sainsbury: only the person asking the example has control over the example! ;)

Comment: @Paul: i don't find it a silly example.  i wish i had asked the question myself.

Comment: I disagree "Worry about performance when you have identified a performance problem." AFAIK OUTPUT parameters will be more efficient so why not just establish this up front and then use the most efficient way by default.

Comment: @Martin: because it's a micro-optimisiation, and experience and my home-boy Knuth said so!

Comment: old old msdn article, might not be valid any longer, but the test shown almost no difference between the two: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978388.aspx

Comment: @Jimmy - Interesting article thanks. Does indeed look like it makes no practical difference.

Comment: Thanks for the added info.  I guess was looking more for "best practice" instead of "most optimised"... But "most optimised" tends to tie closely with "best practice", and in my case our data access layer makes output parameters really simple to use.  So it's more efficient (even if only minutely so), easier to read, and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Output parameters are more light weight.